# Show Jquery EasyUI Function inside Ajax UpdateProgress

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Morning!

I have a asp.net UpdatePanel with an UpdateProgress inside calling a UserControl that fires an animation during the page postback. On this situation, works perfectly, but i'm trying to make a little change on this animation, placing an Easyui progress popup on place.

Here's URL to EasyUI progress popup demo: http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=Messager&theme=default&dir=ltr&pitem=#

Here's my ASPX code:

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <uc1:Loading runat="server" ID="Loading" />
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

and UserControl Page:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Loading.ascx.cs" Inherits="Test.UserControl.Loading" %>

<link href="css/loading.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div class="LoadingContainerBackground">
<div class="LoadingGreyBackground">
</div>
<div class="LoadingTableHolder">
    <table style="text-align: center; width: 100%; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="height: 200px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 38%"></td>
            <td style="width: 20%; height: 175px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">
                <asp:Image ID="update" runat="server" ImageUrl="img/loading.gif" />
            </td>
            <td style="width: 40%"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

On this actual form, works perfectly, but i want to put this in place on same UserControl to avoid redundancy:

```
function progress() {
    var win = $.messager.progress({
        title: 'Please waiting',
        msg: 'Loading data...'
    });
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.messager.progress('close');
    }, 5000)
}
```

and that this event trigger as the current is. Anyone can help me with this?

PS: its important that this event stay on UserControl, because this same event will be used in dozens of pages in project.

PS2: i don't use master page because i prefer to use loose coupling between the pages, to facilitate the diverse between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I put a javascript handler on begin and end of postback to control the time of animation.

Here's the EX:

```
<script>
    Sys.Application.add_init(appl_init);

    function appl_init() {
        var pgRegMgr = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        pgRegMgr.add_beginRequest(BeginHandler);
        pgRegMgr.add_endRequest(EndHandler);
    }

    function BeginHandler() {
        var win = $.messager.progress({
            title: 'Please waiting',
            msg: 'Loading data...'
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
            $.messager.progress('close');
        }, 9999)
    }

    function EndHandler() {
        $.messager.progress('close');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: compatible with all browsers?